# Rails Carrierwave Backgrounder and Sidekiq gems not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, sidekiq, carrierwave-backgrounder

I want to handle uploading `document` `doc`'s(files) to S3 in the background, but for some reason, it doesn't work for me. I'm currently running this locally.

This is my setup:

```
class DocUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

# Include RMagick or MiniMagick support:
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick
  include ::CarrierWave::Backgrounder::Delay

# Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:
  storage :fog

end
```

# /config/initializers/carrierwave_backgrounder.rb

```
CarrierWave::Backgrounder.configure do |c|
  c.backend :sidekiq, queue: :carrierwave
end
```

# documents_controller.rb

```
def document_params
  params.require(:document).permit(
  ..., :doc, :doc_tmp, :remove_doc, ...
)
end
```

# sidekiq.yml

```
---
:queues:
 - [default,5]
 - [carrierwave,5]
```

I run `sidekiq` using the command:

```
bundle exec sidekiq
```

when I try to upload `doc` for `document` with the following setting: (store_in_background)

```
#  doc                 :string  
#  doc_processing      :boolean          default(FALSE), not null  
#  doc_tmp             :string  

class Document < ActiveRecord::Base

  mount_uploader :doc, DocUploader
  store_in_background :doc
  # process_in_background :doc
  attr_accessor :doc_tmp
end
```

it doesn't seem to enqueue any jobs in the background in sidekiq and the `doc` saving is done in-process and it takes a long time.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try sidekiq -q carrierwave
Where you can specify the queue you want to run in development.

Comment: you can do something like  bundle exec sidekiq -C config/sidekiq.yml -q carrierwave else specifying queue name will help too